Are these stalks isomorphic?
If $X$ is a scheme with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ and $h: X \to \text{Spec }\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is the unique morphism of schemes such that $h^\sharp(\text{Spec } \mathcal{O}_X(X)): \mathcal{O}_X(X) \to \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is the identity (this has to do with the universal property of ring spectra).
Is it then true that $$\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec }\mathcal{O}_X(X),h(x)} \cong \mathcal{O}_{X,x}?$$
In particular, I can tell you that here, $h(x)$ is the inverse image of the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_{X,x} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ under the morphism $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}: f \mapsto f_x$ (which is surjective, so that $h(x)$ is in particular a maximal ideal).
Is the isomorphism above true? Any help is appreciated!

Is there a particular hypothesis on $x$? Any point, closed point, rational point over some base field?

@CaptainLama No, $x$ is just an arbitrary point in $X$.

If the scheme $X$ is projective, then the morphism $h$ is a map to a point, isn't it?

@SergeyGuminov That looks like an answer to me.

@SergeyGuminov I mean, if X is projective then its global sections are just $\mathbb{C}$ so its spectrum is a point, yes. But I don't see how that answers my question about the stalks?

That answers your question because the stalk at a closed point of a positive dimensional projective variety is never C.

@red_trumpet It looks like an answer to me too, but I wanted to make sure that the question is stated correctly.

It is very much not true. Take any irreducible proper variety of dimension $n>0$ over a field $k$. Then the map $h$ is a map to the point $\operatorname{Spec} k$ for any point $x\in X$, so $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} k, h(x)}\cong k$, while $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a local ring of positive dimension (unless $x$ is the generic point).
Really, what you are doing is comparing a stalk of a sheaf $F$ to a stalk of some direct image sheaf $h_* F$, and there rarely is any immediate connection between these two for a morphism $h$, except for trivial cases, like when $h$ is an open embedding.

Thanks for the answer!

To help clarify the comments and answer(s?), take the specific example $$X= {\mathbb P}^1_{\mathbb C} =  \mathop{\rm spec} {\mathbb C}[t]\cup \infty.$$  Suppose that $x\in X$ is (corresponds to) the maximal ideal $(t-0)$ of ${\mathbb C}[t]$. Then the local ring ${\cal O}_{X,x} = {\mathbb C}[t]_{(t-0)}$, which is not $\mathbb C$, as it would have to be, if the statement were true.
